# How to get element with key in list of dicts

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a list of objects like this:

```
let colors = [
  {
    id: 0,
    color: "green",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    color: "blue",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    color: "orange",
  },
];
```

What is the best way (most optimized) to get an element with `id=1`... is there a way to do it without iterating through the list?

Comment: is the list ordered? have you tried anything?

Comment: No. There is no way to do that without iterating through the array. Even if there exists a method to directly get the object with that id, there will be some sort of iteration done behind the scenes.

Comment: @NinaScholz the list is not ordered... I tried iterating through the whole list and checking if an element's id matches the one i want... but this seems to slow if the list is big

Comment: @WaisKamal How could I break out of the loop once I find the id? Or are there other ways to optimize the iteration further?

Comment: Normally, you'd have to iterate the whole list. But, if the list is ordered by `id` then it would be `log(n)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Use the `break` statement.

Comment: Optimized for what access pattern?  Seems to me like you probably want to build an index (which **does** iterate the list) like this: `index = {}; colors.forEach(item => index[item.id] = item)`  Then after an index has been created the item can be accessed as `index[id]` **without iterating the list**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small tip:

- Use const instead of let when you're not reassigning values

Try doing the following:

```
                          // ✅ good pattern: destructuring. We only use what we need
const myColor = colors.find(({ id }) => id === 1)
```

Comment: This seems like the best way... is this better under the hood than reduce or just iterating?

Comment: @NickSmith This is the same as just iterating on each lookup.

Comment: Teemu: Having a predictable code it's better than not having one, that's why; If you can assume that your variables won't be changed at anytime, you're following the ```immutability``` principle. And special for javascript arrays you don't need to reassign to change its value, never. But it's just a tip anyway, follow if you want it to.

Comment: @NickSmith in the end they're both loops, they iterate over your array, but using reduce you are taking another variable into the loop ( the ```carrier``` or ```accumulator``` ). Check the diffs here [#array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) & [#array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: @FelipeMalara Umm .. How should I implement an immutable loop counter ; ). After your edit the answer is much better.

Comment: @Teemu thanks indeed. In this case, the reduce fits just perfect, like ```[1,2,3].reduce((counter, element) => counter + element, 0)``` should return 6

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the whole array once and create a lookup table if the array is static. Then, lookups can be done in constant time after `O(n)` preprocessing.

```js
let colors = [
  {
    id: 0,
    color: "green",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    color: "blue",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    color: "orange",
  },
];
const lookup = colors.reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr.id] = curr, acc), {});
console.log(lookup[1]);
console.log(lookup[2]);
```